# Is it possible to get originals HQ images from CIFAR10 dataset?

Tags: image, neural-network

I'm currently working on my thesis on the neural networks. I'm using the CIFAR10 as a reference dataset. Now I would like to show some example results in my paper. The problem is, that the images in the dataset are 32x32 pixels so it's really hard to recognize something on them when printed on paper.

Is there any way to get hold of the original images with higher resolution?

UPDATE: I'm not asking for image processing algorithm, but for the original images presented in CIFAR-10. I need some higher resolution samples to put in my paper.

Comment: Difficult for you or the algorithm? Obviously, the ANN should be able to do it since the CIFAR10 data set is used for object recognition. Maybe you're doing something wrong? If you're writing your own learner, try using an off-the-shelf solution to help debug your code.

Comment: @Emre I'm not asking for ANN algorithm, but for the original files. I have edited the question.

Comment: That was clear. I asked WHY you need it, since the learners can train on the tiny images just fine.

Comment: For my paper. I need to show some results, but the 32x32 is too small for print.

Comment: so what's your final solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now have the same problem and I just found your question.

It seems that [CIFAR](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) was built from labeling [the tinyimages dataset](http://horatio.cs.nyu.edu/mit/tiny/data/index.html), and are kind enough to share the indexing from CIFAR to tinyimages. Now tinyimages contain metadata file with URL of the original images and a toolbox for getting for any image you wish (e.g. those included in the CIFAR index).

So one may write a mat file which does this and share the results...

Comment: hey did you successfully do it? I face exactly the same problem as you can you share some details?

Comment: What I did - and maybe what others are doing - is just to move to ImageNet where bounding-box labeling is available along with the original-sized image.

Comment: you mean download the images from imagenet and resize to what i want?

Comment: @Pwan, yes. But this require to cut the bounding boxes from the original image yourself.

Comment: how so? I am not talking about the distribution that is for object detection problem.

Answer (score 1):

They're just small:

> The CIFAR-10 and CIFAR-100 are [labeled subsets](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) of the 80 million **tiny** images dataset.

You could use Google reverse image search if you're curious.

Comment: I have considered this option, but it's no use. Googles algorithms and database are not powerfull/big enough to be any use.